# How to take only time part of TIMESTAMP without time zone and put it inside datagridview using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, timestamp

I have a problem with converting DateTime format into datagridview. Basically the case is this: in database I have 4 columns with type: TIMESTAMP without time zone. I reach for that data from database using SQL query and what I want is to write TIMESTAMP without time zone type without date, only time.

Ex.
first row column "Arrival" has value: "2017-03-08 14:44:32", I want to take "14:44:32" from that cell and place it into datagridview, column "Arrival". When I make a command like:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
     string spremanje_string = row["Arrival"].ToString();
     string pretvorba = spremanje_string.Substring(spremanje_string.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
     row["Arrival"] = DateTime.ParseExact(pretvorba, "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 }
```

(Dont mind foreach, its just part of code from that loop).

C# gives me a error saying:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a `DateTime` instead of just a `string` or maybe a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: I didn't make the rules =)

Comment: You want a date time without a date? That isnt a datetime

Comment: The thing is, datetime is for database purpose, what I want is for user part, its more clear to read when you dont have 4 columns with date + time, and one column with that same date..... so you will understand now why.

Comment: When adding the DateTime to the DataGridView just do dateTime.TimeOfDay instead of DateTime

Comment: I dont understand @EpicKip, I get data from database using datatable as you can see, i fill datagridview with data from that database, and this part of code you see is just editing couple of columns to show only time, time is already present in database.

Comment: I posted a solution, I suggest you read it carefully

Comment: @MarkoPetrePetričević I added a one liner solution (nr. 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 solutions,

1. Set DefaultCellStyle **easiest method**
2. Set the format after you filled your dataGridView (what you tried in your ForEach).
3. Set the format before the data goes in.

**Example nr 1:**

```
dataGridViewName.Columns["columnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Form‌​‌​at = "HH:mm:ss";
```

**Example nr 2:**

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string dateTime = row["Arrival"].ToString();
    string time = dateTime.Split(' ')[1];
    //Do not convert to DateTime, no use if you will only use it to display (string)
    row.Cells["Arrival"].Value = time;
}
```

**Example nr 3:**

When adding the date value to the DataGridView (this won't work with a DataSource as far as I know):

```
dateTimeValue.TimeOfDay.ToString()
```

Comment: I have a question: in Ex. nr 1: do you mean that I need to do that AFTER I do: `datagridview1.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: That foreach is based on yours, place it wherever you had it. But considering it takes a value from the DataGrid, the Grid must have values first.

Comment: Yes after you assign the DataSource

Comment: @MarkoPetrePetričević I added an easier method, the last one. I suggest you use that one as it doesn't have to be in a loop and is just a single line.

Comment: Did it, when I start debugging, It says variable time is time part, and everything seems good, but it doesnt show it like that on datagridview, Im confused, everything I do, debugging shows me good, but when it shows on datagridview it doesnt apply that change.

Comment: Do the last fix, that one is formatting it will surely work

Comment: Where should I add that, I tried in foreach loop (doesnt make sence) and DefaultCellStyle is underlined all the time, I placed it before filling datagridview and after, but its always underlined....any solution?

Comment: Underlined? You mean it shows it as an error? It should be `dataGridViewName.Columns["columnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Format`

Comment: Oh no... Are you using winforms or not? I am giving you fix's for winforms

Comment: @MarkoPetrePetričević No problem ^^ thanks for accepting my answer

Comment: ´could you edit ur answer, just put `dataGridViewName.Columns["columnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Form‌​at`, coz thats basically the answer to my question.

Comment: @MarkoPetrePetričević I will put that as example nr1, this answer is also for other people

Comment: I dont have anything against it, its just that for my problem only solution is example nr1, and if someone has the same problem that will lead them to answer, other 2 wont, but do as you please =)

Comment: @MarkoPetrePetričević Other 2 will work if you don't add data via DataSource, especially last one. Edited the 2nd one because it was slightly wrong

Answer (score 0):

If your row["Arrival"] is DateTime you can use .TimeOfDay.

This gives you a TimeSpan.

So you have several possible solutions here:

- You can change the type of row["Arrival"] to be TimeSpan and get TimeOfDay when your read from Database.
- If you just need to display the time (no sorting, editing) use .ToString("HH:mm:ss") on the DateTime to get a string.
- If you are using WPF you can use a DataGridTextColumn and StringFormat={HH:mm:ss} in your binding